# How do i extract from Mysql a json, and save in php variable?

Tags: php, json, extract

I've been looking everywhere, but maybe i don't know exactly what i'm looking for.
In a wordpress site, this plugin stores the form answers to mysql. The value i need is in a column called `fields` and what is stored there is:

```
[
   {"name":"Name","value":"me you","id":0,"type":"name","first":"me","middle":"","last":"you"},
   {"name":"Email","value":"myemail@gmail.com","id":1,"type":"email"},
   {"name":"Phone","value":"+12015550000","id":2,"type":"phone"},
   {"name":"Address","value":"my address\nsomecity, somestate\nsomepost\nUS","id":3,"type":"address","address1":"my address","address2":"","city":"somecity","state":"somestate","postal":"somepost","country":"US"}
]
```

This look json to me, but im very new to this, so my question is, what do i do to get from this, to extract the `address` (example) to a php variable?

Thank you very much for your time and have a great day.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?